# Relationship between eigenvalues of A symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{pmatrix} \in M_2\mathbb{(R)}$$

i) Find the eigenvalues of $A$

ii) If $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $A$, prove that $\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of A.

For the first part, by using quadratic formula I get,
$$\lambda=\frac{a+c\pm\sqrt{(a-c)^2+4b^2}}{2}$$

Please help me check whether the eigenvalues I get is correct or not. If yes, how can I relate this eigenvalue with the eigenvectors given?

Comment: @Amzoti so how can I get the eigenvalues with the eigenvectors given since there are 3 unknowns for the eigenvalue.

Comment: Note that (ii) doesn't ask you to find the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: You've already answered i). Regarding ii), use Av= $\lambda$ v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector, then:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a+2b\\b+2c\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

So $\lambda = a+2b$ and $b+2c=2\lambda = 2(a+2b)$ or $2a+3b-2c=0$.

Now $$A\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-2a+b\\-2b+c\end{pmatrix}$$

And you need to show that $-2a+b = -2(-2b+c)$.

Comment: $\binom12$ is an eigenVECTOR, right?

Comment: it will be easier, in this case, to substitute $b$ from the first two equations in the right hand side of the second.

Comment: No reason to substitute $b$, it's far simpler than that. @abel

Comment: i guess should have said that i find it easier to eliminate $b$ using the corresponding components of the two equations.

Comment: The first equation says $2a+3b-2c=0$. I think from this you can easily conclude that $-2a+b=-2(-2b+c)$ without elimination...

Comment: i got it. how will you generalize this method to matrices of size greater than two?

Comment: More generally? That wasn't the question above, but if then you'd be stuck doing some sort of elimination. But for this problem, completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

for part II, use the fact that symmetric matrices have a full set of orthogonal eigenvectors spanning the whole space $R^n.$ this theorem is called the spectral decomposition theorem for symmetric matrices. anyway, if you have one eigenvector $(1,2)^T$ then $(-2,1)^T$ is orthogonal to the first one, therefore must be another  eigenvector of the matrix.

edit: thomas andrews has a better answer that does not resort to the spectral theorem in the case of $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix.